# PHP/mysqli multiple select statements active fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm modifying some web pages to use prepared statements in mysqli, rather than just mysqli::query() and it appears that I can't have multiple select statements active.

That is, I have a bit of code like this (queries are simplified in this example, i.e. removed any joins or WHERE and ORDER):

```
$q=$DB->prepare("SELECT * from Table1");
if (!$q->execute())
   some_error_function();
$res=$q->get_result();

$q2=$DB->prepare("SELECT * from Table2");
if (!$q2->execute())
   some_error_function();
$res2=$q2->get_result();

combine_and_present_result($res1,$res2);
```

However, it bails out on the $q2->execute() line, and to be clear: the some_error_function() doesn't run, instead my apache error log reports that it can't call execute() on a non-object. i.e. the $q2->prepare is failing.

Adding some more error output I find that the error I get on prepare is this:

```
PREPARE FAILED - 2014 = Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I don't understand this; I am not using transactions, and the queries are selects which are non-blocking and besides, they are on different (innoDB) tables. I'm using different variables so I believe the two things should be independent.

Of course, there are workarounds to this (e.g. I'm not sure if I can safely issue q->close() before I've done $res->free(), but I can pull all the results out and so pass arrays, not mysqli_results to combine_and_present_result) but I don't understand why this is failing, and I would like to know WHAT the problem is, not just avoid it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is $DB the direct result of a mysqli connect or a class defined in the code?

Comment: it can't be. create  **working** simplified version and see it yourself.then check what's wrong with your non-simplified version

Comment: on a side note, there shouldn't be such a thing like some_error_function(); leave your database interactions alone and just let them report errors by themselves. [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Comment: @NigelRen - $DB is the result of a $DB=new mysqli() statement.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - you are right, sorry, in the above I had a slight error, my failing code actually had the `$res=$q->get_result()` AFTERthe second prepare statement. In that position it fails, if I move it to as above (i.e. get_result on $q runs before preparing $q2) it works.

Still don't understand why the second query should fail if I haven't done the get_result though!

Comment: Let me google it for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: On your second point: if the `$q->execute()` fails, no error is reported and then the get_result() function fails, so the PHP bails, giving a blank screen and an entry in the error log: I prefer to catch this and provide either an error message or an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: so you are adding a dedicated error checking for the *every* query you run. Call it programming?

Comment: OK well, thanks for the help - not sure the sarcasm is really warranted though. FWIW, yes, I do enclose every `execute()` if an if statement (none of these are big pages), certainly why developing/debugging, with a common error routine called on failure.

Comment: Well you you like your code bloated with error checking repeated again and again - why not